# R error : type 'closure' cannot be coerced to 'double'

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to convert numeric values to percent in R using `scales` package.

But I am getting `type 'closure' cannot be coerced to 'double'` error

```
library(data.table)
library(scales)

dt<- as.data.table(mtcars)

#Convert the numeric values to percentage
value_column_names <- setdiff(names(dt), c("mpg", "disp", "hp"))

#Change values to percentage format
dt[, (value_column_names) :=
                lapply(.SD, function(x) scales::percent_format(x, accuracy = 0.01))
              , .SDcols = value_column_names]
```

```
Error:
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`((value_column_names), lapply(.SD, function(x) scales::percent_format(x,  : 
  type 'closure' cannot be coerced to 'double'
```

Not sure where I have to change to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `scales::percent` :

```
library(data.table)

dt[, (value_column_names) := lapply(.SD, scales::percent, 
              scale = 1, accuracy = 0.01), .SDcols = value_column_names]
dt
#     mpg   cyl  disp  hp  drat    wt   qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
# 1: 21.0 6.00% 160.0 110 3.90% 2.62% 16.46% 0.00% 1.00% 4.00% 4.00%
# 2: 21.0 6.00% 160.0 110 3.90% 2.88% 17.02% 0.00% 1.00% 4.00% 4.00%
# 3: 22.8 4.00% 108.0  93 3.85% 2.32% 18.61% 1.00% 1.00% 4.00% 1.00%
# 4: 21.4 6.00% 258.0 110 3.08% 3.22% 19.44% 1.00% 0.00% 3.00% 1.00%
# 5: 18.7 8.00% 360.0 175 3.15% 3.44% 17.02% 0.00% 0.00% 3.00% 2.00%
#...
#...
```

Obviously , there are way do this without using `scales` package at all.

Comment: Hi Ronak! the scales::percent() function converts numeric to character type in final result. I want to avoid that and  want the final result to display the same as yours but the type should be numeric. Both in str() and also if I export it to a xlsx file.

Comment: It is not possible to have characters like `%` in the output with their class as numeric in R. `%` is not number. So if you want to keep `%` it's class will be character or you can keep output as 6.00 if you want to keep them as numeric.

Comment: ,Thanks Ronak! that makes sense. I was  a bit curious as in excel the numbers can have ```%``` symbol while retaining the type as number. I will try to do a bit more search and see if I can have numbers as you have said but export such that they have ```%``` in excel along with number type before closing this question off.